# Fail back from slave to master in Artemis colocated HA config is not working

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a 4 node Artemis 2.10 cluster on Linux configured for async IO journal, replication and colocated HA servers. I have been testing the failover and fail back but its not working.  When shutting down one server (A) in an HA pair the colocated backup on the second server (B) will activate and correctly processes messages intended for the original server A. I modified the ColocatedFailoverExample from Artemis examples to check this and it is working. The problem is that when I bring up the original server A it starts, becomes live, registers acceptors and addresses and joins the cluster but a number of things are wrong:

1. looking at the artemis console for server A there is no longer a colocated_backup_1 listed to show that it is providing a colocated backup to server B.
2. Server A coming back up causes the server that was failed over to, server B, to go totally offline and only function as a backup. The master it was providing stops and no longer displays addresses or accepters in the UI.
3. Although it says its running as a backup Server B also doesn't have the colocated_backup_1 object shown in its console either.
4. Server B seems to be part of the cluster still but in the UI there is no green master node shown for it anymore - just a red slave node circle. Client connections to server B fail, most likely because the colocated master that was running on it was shutdown.
5. In the Artemis UI for server B under node-name > cluster-connections > cluster-name the attributes for the cluster show no nodes in the node array and the node id is wrong. The node id is now the same as the id of the master broker on server A. Its almost as if the information for the colocated_backup_01 broker on server B that was running before failover has replaced the server B live server and there's now only one broker on server B - the colocated backup.

This all happens immediately when I bring up server A. The UI for server B immediately refreshes at that time and the colocated_backup_01 entry disappears and the acceptors and addresses links under what was the master broker name for server B just disappear. The cluster attributes page will refresh and the 3 nodes that were listed there in the "nodes" attribute disappear and the "nodes" attribute is empty.

Now if I take down server B instead and bring it up, the roles between the server pair are swapped.  Now server B becomes live again and is shown as a master node in the topology (but still no colocated_backup_01 in the UI) and the server A master broker goes offline and server A reconfigures as a backup/slave node. Whether server A or B is in this "offline", broker backup-only state the value of the Node property in the cluster attributes shown in the UI is the same value for both. Prior to doing the failover test they had different node ids which makes sense but the colocated_backup_01 backup on each did share the node id of the node it was backing up.

To summarize what I think is happening:  The master that is coming backup after failover seems to trigger its partner backup node to come up as a backup but to also stop being a master node itself. From that point the pair colocation stops and there is only ever one live master between the two servers instead of one on each. The fail-back feature seems to be not only failing the original master back but shutting down the colocated master on that backup as well. Almost as if the topology between the two was configured to be colocated and its treating it a the standard two-node HA config where one server is the master and one is the slave.

The only way to fix the issue with the pair is to stop both servers and 
remove everything under the broker "data" directory on both 
boxes before starting them again. Just removing the colocated backup files on each machine isn't enough - everything under "data" has to go. After doing this they come up correctly and both are live masters and they pair up as HA colocated backups for each other again.

Here is the ha-policy section of the broker.xml file which is the same for all 4 servers:

```
  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <colocated>
           <backup-request-retries>5</backup-request-retries>
           <backup-request-retry-interval>5000</backup-request-retry-interval>
           <max-backups>1</max-backups>
           <request-backup>true</request-backup>
           <backup-port-offset>20</backup-port-offset>
           <master>
                <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
                <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
           </master>
           <slave>
              <max-saved-replicated-journals-size>-1</max-saved-replicated-journals-size>
              <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
              <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
              <restart-backup>false</restart-backup>
           </slave>
        </colocated>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

Comment: I think this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. There are also too many moving pieces and too many problems. I recommend you focus your question down to a single point (instead of 5 different ones) and reduce the number of moving pieces to only what is absolutely necessary to reproduce the behavior you're seeing. For example, are all 4 nodes required to reproduce the problem? If not, eliminate any unnecessary nodes. My guess is that 2 would be sufficient. A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be great.

Comment: It's also worth noting that steps involving a manual process like inspecting a web console is going to be tedious and error prone for anybody trying to reproduce this problem. A functional test demonstrating the problem (e.g. a messaging client failing to make a connection or send a message when it should succeed) is better, not least because it can be automated. It also eliminates the possibility that the console itself (or whatever is being observed) is broken while the underlying technology is functioning as it should.

Comment: HI Justin, I'm describing a configuration that is supposed to work (according to the configuration properties I've shown there) but its not working. I'm also describing the behavior that seems incorrect - which are the 5 points you refer to. I posted this to the activemq user list but got no response. I'm just trying to establish what the correct behavior should be for fail-back as its not working as described in the user manual.  I wanted confirmation from the developers or other users that colocated HA fail-back should work and that either my configuration is wrong or I need to open a defect

Comment: I understand and agree that it doesn't appear to be working. I'm a developer on ActiveMQ, and I'm approaching this issue from that angle. Any problem has to be reproduced programmatically first to confirm the problem is legitimate, second to verify the fix, and third to mitigate the risk of future regressions. It helps a ton and is common practice for the user reporting the problem to create a reproducer. The best reproducers are functional and don't require manual steps. That's what I'm looking for here. There are just too many details and observations to sort out in my free time.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll open a Jira defect and provide the modified version of the colocated HA test case that I used to reproduce this behavior. We can continue the discussion in the Jira comments as I'd like some pointers on where to look to provide more information. I can load a server in the debugger and trace behavior if I know where to start. Also I can reproduce this with two physical servers and haven't tried with the environment that is used for running Artemis examples which runs multiple nodes on the same server. I will try that as well.